# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321 after deployment react js

Tags: reactjs, build

I'm trying to deployed a simple web app with react js.

My server is working fine and all my app is working fine on a dev mode.

But when i make a build , i put my build folder on my public folder , my web app appeared 1sec then i have white screen . When i opened my consol i have this error

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

When i delete my static folder from my public folder i have the web app ok on my dev environnement. So i think the problem is comming from the static folder but i don't know what :(

Evrytime the error bring me to this part

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

react 17.0.2
React dom 17.0.2